# How Xcode-11.7 can build the project for iPhone(iOS-14) and also shows the debug log in Xcode console?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, ios14, xcode12

In my Macbook, i have Xcode 11.7 installed and somehow my iPhone OS updated to iOS-14.

Then i couldn't build and run my project to the iPhone as Xcode-11.7 doesn't have device support for iOS-14.

**Scenario 01:**

I downloaded Xcode-12 and copied the iOS-14 device support file to Xcode-11.7.
When i build the project by Xcode-11.7 for iPhone-iOS14. It's only install the app to my iPhone by showing an error pop up[image]

but there are no log showing in the xcode console.

Then i found the Xcode-12 release note

*`Xcode 12 now encrypts the connection between Xcode and paired devices, protecting against an attacker in a privileged network position executing arbitrary code on connected iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, or tvOS devices during a remote debug session. (60386733) These security benefits are available when Xcode 12 connects to devices running iOS 14, iPadOS 14, watchOS 7, tvOS 14, or later versions. These OS versions also refuse debugger connections from older Xcode releases. Xcode 12 continues to support debugging for older OS versions, but without the new encryption.`*

By this notes, it is clear that Xcode-11.7 or lower version should not be able to show debug log in the console from iPhone which OS is 14 or higher even though we use the hacky method to put device support file.

**Scenario 02:**

Some of my colleague are using Xcode-11.7 to build on iPhone-iOS14. They are not getting any issue what i'm getting in *Scenario 01*. The difference is that they downloaded the *iOS-14 device support file* from a github repo instead of coping from Xcode-12. Then i also tried to copy the *iOS-14 device support file* from that github repo & fortunately it also worked for me!

Now my question is

1. How is that possible to connect the debug session with iPhone-iOS14 using Xcode-11.7 where apple official release note pointed that it should not work?
2. The copy of *iOS-14 device support file* from Xcode-12 to Xcode-11.7 is not working but why its working when dowloaded from github repo?